# Explaining Mid for SharePoint Calculated Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

```
=MID([Title],1,FIND(".",[Title],1)-1)
```

This grabs the first word before the "." How would I find the next word after "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=MID([Title], FIND(".", [Title])+1, LEN([Title]))
```

You could also wrap it in an if so that it just shows nothing if there is no period

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(".",[Title])),MID([Title],FIND(".",[Title])+1,LEN([Title])),"")
```

Here is an MSDN page with a pretty comprehensive set of the 2010 calculated columns that I use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: How would I get it to not return the "."

Comment: Edited to skip the period, the second argument in mid is where to start, we were using FIND(".", [Title]) so we just needed to add 1